# SQL GROUP BY "HAVING" the required rows

Tags: mysql, sql, having

Is there a succinct way of using `HAVING` to check if the required rows are within the `GROUP BY`?

With the example date:

```
turtle_id   name  
1           Mike
2           Ralph
3           Leo
4           Don
```

and

```
turtle_id   crush_for
1           Pizza
1           April Oneil
2           April Oneil
3           Pizza
3           April Oneil
4           Pizza
4           Pizza
4           Science
4           April Oneil
```

And the SQL:

```
SELECT turtle.name
FROM turtle
JOIN turtle_crush ON turtle_crush.turtle_id = turtle.turtle_id
WHERE turtle_crush.crush_for IN ('Pizza', 'April Oneil')
GROUP BY turtle.turtle_id
HAVING (a crush on both "Pizza" and "April Oneil")
```

I realize I could do something like `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`, but that would give a false positive for Don (id 4) because he likes 'Pizza' twice.

**Edit:**
Just adding a `WHERE` clause will return Ralph where he doesn't have a `crush_for` 'Pizza'

Comment: Put WHERE before GROUP BY.

Comment: @Strawberry That's a good point Strawberry. Ideally strings (e.g. 'Pizza') don't make good primary keys, and all tables should be normalized, but the way it is makes asking a question simpler.

Comment: @Strawberry, In a more "correct" scenario, we could have something like 'Pepperoni Pizza' and 'Cheese Pizza', with `INT` primary keys of 1 and 2 respectively. These two pizzas could then be related to a parent category named "Food". The original question would then ask how to return all the turtles who have a crush on at least one "Food" item and at least one "Person" item and there would need to be an extra `JOIN` on the "parent category" table and the "items" table.

Comment: @Strawberry ... The primary key would be the `INT` 1 or 2 - as my response to your question describes... The "turtle_crush" table would then look more like 4 => 1 and 4 => 2.

Comment: @Strawberry. Then the primary key for the "turtle_crush" table would be a compound key. Row 4-1 (Don and 'Pepperoni Pizza') and row 4-2 (Don and 'Cheese Pizza')  would each be unique and in normal form.

Comment: You're just not paying attention. I give up.

Comment: @Strawberry Down voting my SO question for patiently answering your questions at length is not constructive nor honest.

Comment: If you take time to review your data set in the context of your remarks, then a penny may drop somewhere, in which case the exercise will have proved constructive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT t.turtle_name
FROM turtle t
INNER JOIN (SELECT turtle_id
            FROM turtle_crush
            WHERE crush_for IN ('Pizza','April Oneil')
            GROUP BY turtle_id
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT crush_for) = 2) tc
    on t.turtle_id = tc.turtle_id;
```

In this code, the subquery first filter the results where `crush_for` is either `'Pizza'` or `'April Oneil'`. Then it groups by `turtle_id`, with another condition of choosing those `turtle_id`s that have 2 different `crush_for` values (hence ensuring that you get only the `turtle_id`s that have both crushes). Then it's joined with the `turtle` table to get the name.

Comment: but this would also count for `crush_for` if there is a `turtle` with crushes on `Science` and `Pizza`. So its not quite right, is it?

Comment: @Nebi No, that won't happen, because there's a `WHERE crush_for IN ('Pizza','April Oneil')`

Comment: +1 @ Lamak yeah, nevermind. I thought of twice in Piaaza without April, but it doenst matter either. I was wrong.

Comment: @Lamak Thanks for your help Lamak.

Answer (score 1):

Put the list of crushes in the `WHERE` clause, group by turtle ID, count the distinct values of crush types then keep only the groups that have at least 2 values (or how many crushes you put in the query):

```
SELECT turtle.name
FROM turtle
  INNER JOIN turtle_crush ON turtle_crush.turtle_id = turtle.turtle_id
WHERE crush_for IN ("Pizza", "April Oneil")
GROUP BY turtle.turtle_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT crush_for) = 2
```